# Replacing a specific part of a query string PHP

Tags: php, regex, string

I use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` to get the query sting.

A example would be `a=123&b=456&c=789`

How could I remove the b value from the query string to obtain `a=123&c=789` where b can be any value of any length and is alpha numeric.

Any ideas appreciated, thanks.

Comment: SO rock but you are not. cause you have accepted a solution which will fail to replace many kinds of data.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: What kind of data would the solution not able to replace? The OP could then be interested of the case where the query parameters contains only numbers (as reported in the example query); if this the case, the proposed solution would work.

Comment: @kiamlaluno well if you take this site as "let's answer every lame question and forget it" it's o.k. But someone thinks of this site as an ultimate source of knowledge, where answers can be used more than once

Comment: @pondpad: See the comments to my answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308711#comments-3308749).

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: The question is specific; I don't think someone can say the replies given here are generally valid. Generally speaking, the answer given to a question could not be valid in other cases; if in a case the solution is to use regular expressions, that doesn't mean regular expressions should always be used.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel Don't cry, it suits my needs. Of course its my responsibility to consider encoding and any other exploits. Surely it is ridiculous to expect a complete solution which is suitable for any case. I asked the questing thinking that I possibly needed regex when actually what I needed was hell of alot simpler. Let me rephrase my previous comment. Most people at Stack Overflow rock, I appreciate how alot of people try and help and go into detail. However of course there are some people who pass their time trolling in the comments.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The value is going to be `$_GET['b']`.

How about:

```
str_replace('&b='.$_GET['b'], '', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
```

Comment: This solution fails if the value contains characters that need to be encoded. See Col. Shrapnel’s comment in the comments to my answer (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308711#comment-3428781) for an example.

Comment: Ah, yes. But you could fix that easy enough by wrapping $_GET['b'] in a decode thingy.

Comment: What if there is a `?` before `b=`?

Answer (score 15):

A solution using url parsing:

```
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $result_array);
unset($result_array['b']);
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] = http_build_query($result_array);
```

Comment: Something like this, definitely. You may be able to use the existing `$_GET` rather than doing the initial `parse_str()`: `unset($_GET['b']); $qs = http_build_query($_GET);`

Comment: The difference is that my answer affects only the `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` variable, and leaves $_GET untouched, in case it would still be needed for some reason.

Answer (score 4):

you can use this function:

```
function Remove_QS_Key($url, $key) {
$url = preg_replace('/(?:&|(\?))'.$key.'=[^&]*(?(1)&|)?/i', "$1", $url);
return $url;
}
```

to remove any key you want, e.g.

```
echo Remove_QS_Key("http://domain.com/?a=b&ref=dusername&c=d&e=f&g=h", "ref");
```

result

```
http://www.domain.com/?a=b&c=d&e=f&g=h
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$query_new = preg_replace('/(^|&)b=[^&]*/', '', $query);
```

Comment: What’s the reason for the down vote? And please don’t say “Oh, you’re using regular expressions! How bad!”

Comment: Using a regular expression would allow to replace the parameter whatever position it has in the query string. `str_replace('&b='.$_GET['b'], '', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])` doesn't replace it if it's the first parameter in the query string.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Exactly. That’s why I chose a regular expression search.

Comment: imagine we have `$_GET['b'] = "direct replace sometimes fail";`

Comment: @Gumbo: I take that sometimes the code shown from who creates the question is taken too literally; the fact the parameter `b` is shown in second position doesn't mean it should be always in second position. The OP is asking to remove that parameter, but he doesn't say it is always the second parameter, nor is it never the first parameter. That's why I think your answer is valid as other answers. If then the OP prefers an array instead of a string, that is something the OP should report.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: `/[^&]*/` matches "direct replace sometimes fail", as well as "direct+replace+sometimes+fail"; I fail to see what your objection is.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: I think Col. Shrapnel’s comment was to address the flaw the accepted answer has that is requires the value to be unencoded. In opposite to that if `$_GET['b']` equals `direct replace sometimes fail` the value in the query string can either be `direct+replace+sometimes+fail`, `direct%20replace%20sometimes%20fail` or even a combination of `+` and `%20` but it’s never `direct replace sometimes fail`.

Comment: @Gumbo: As you proposed to use `preg_replace()`, I take that the variable `$query` you are referring to is a copy of `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`; maybe that should be made clear in your answer. The question doesn't report how the obtained result is used; as the question is only how to remove a query parameter from the query string, your answer replies to what the OP asked. If then he needs to re-encode the string before to use it, that is a different question.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: `$query` can contain any valid query string. This solution does not depend on an actually requested query string that is parsed by PHP in advance to obtain an array of its parameters (i.e. `$_GET`) like other suggestions do (just like your own). And it does not require any specific parameter presence or parameter order neither.

Comment: @Gumbo: I didn't say your answer was not correct. I am simply saying that the comment made from Col. Shrapnel doesn't make sense for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

All the answers look good, but it will be more flexible if you do:

```
// Make a copy of $_GET to keep the original data
$getCopy = $_GET;
unset($getCopy['b']); // or whatever var you want to take out

// This is your cleaned array
var_dump($getCopy);

// If you need the URL-encoded string, just use http_build_query()
$encodedString = http_build_query($getCopy);
```

Comment: In PHP 5.3 `$getCopy = $_GET` doesn't create a copy, but it creates a reference to `$_GET`. I had the same problem in my code, where I wanted to preserve the value of `$_GET` that was used for another function; I used `$query = $_GET; unset($query['q'];`, and the result has been that also the other function (which was accessing `$_GET` directly) was not able to retrieve `$_GET['q']`.

Comment: As far as I know, to create a reference you will need to do `$getCopy =& $_GET`...

Comment: @ilarra: That's correct; only objects are passed by reference, in PHP 5.3. I cannot then generalize the code I reported, even though replacing `$query = $_GET; unset($query['q'];` with the loop resolved the issue present in my code.

Answer (score 1):

You simply make a variable using `$_GET` and exclude `b` query string in build process:

```
$query_string_new = 'a=' . urlencode($_GET['a']) . '&c=' . urlencode($_GET['c']);
```

The `$query_string_new` should now contain `a=123&c=789`

Comment: Don’t forget to escape the output properly.

Comment: And what if *a* and *c* are not decimal values?

Comment: @Gumbo: What do you mean exactly?, are you asking or need to suggest something here?

Comment: @sAc: If you use `urlencode` instead of `intval`, it can be used on any values.

Answer (score 0):

Pear already has a class(Net_URL2) that handles URL parsing/building:

Install via Composer: https://packagist.org/packages/pear/net_url2
Install as include: https://github.com/pear/Net_URL2/blob/master/Net/URL2.php

Example code:

```
$url = new Net_URL2('http://www.example.com/?one=1');
$url->setQueryVariable('two', 2);
echo $url; // http://www.example.com/?one=1&two=2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a  function to replace a query parameter: (like `example.com?a=1&b=2` -> `example.com?a=5&b=2`)

```
function replace_qs_key($key, $value) {
  $current_url = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") .
                 "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
  $current_url_without_qs = strtok($current_url, '?');
  parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $query_params);
  $query_params['page'] = $value;
  $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] = http_build_query($query_params);
  $new_url = $current_url_without_qs .'?'. $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  return $new_url;
}
```