# Change single variable value in querystring

Tags: php, regex, url-rewriting

I am given a page url like `'http://abc.com/test.php?a=1&b=2&c=3'`. Now I have been told to change the value of b to 5 so that it becomes `'http://abc.com/test.php?a=1&b=5&c=3'`.

i.e change from `http://abc.com/test.php?a=1&b=2&c=3` to `http://abc.com/test.php?a=1&b=5&c=3`

Note: variable b here can refer to any name.

Comment: Do you want to do this on just one single page, or for that query string variable across lots of different pages?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use

- [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url) to extract the query string from the URL
- [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/parse_str) to split the query string into an array
- [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/array_merge) to add a new array `"b" => 5`
- [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/http_build_query) to re-build a query string
- The remaining parts from the first step (protocol, host, path...)  to re-build the full URL or - if you have the `HTTP` pecl extension - a [`http_build_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-url.php) with [`HTTP_URL_JOIN_QUERY`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/http.constants.php) will alleviate much of the work.

Comment: Since this question is closed, but getting a lot of traffic, I thought it useful to mention that Pear has a class that handles all of this. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/33109595/3852461