# Change PHP GET with link?

Tags: php

I'd like to create a link that changes a PHP `$_GET` variable. For example:

```
URL: http://site.com/index&variable=hello&anothervariable=dontchangeme

<a href="variable=world">Click me</a>

(after click)

URL: http://site.com/index&variable=world&anothervariable=dontchangeme
```

I know you can do this to just change the page (`href="1.html"`), but I'd like to do the same thing while maintaining the GET variables that were already there.

Comment: Use window.location and add the required fields. I think its best done on Javascipt.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809774/manipulate-a-url-string-by-adding-get-parameters

Comment: You probably need to write some rewriting rules in the .htaccess file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$query = array('variable' => 'world') + $_GET;

printf('<a href="index?%s">Click me</a>', http_build_query($query));
```

See http://php.net/http_build_query. That's the easy to understand minimal version. Correctly you need to also HTML-escape the generated query string (because you're putting it into HTML):

```
printf('<a href="index?%s">Click me</a>', htmlspecialchars(http_build_query($query)));
```

Comment: That seems interesting, it would nice if you explain the above code :)

Comment: If you read the documentation and play around with this a bit, it's pretty self-explanatory. You merge the existing `$_GET` array and your new value(s), then build a query string from them and put them in a link.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply redirect the user changing the variable value and using `header()`..

```
if(isset($_GET['variable'] && $_GET['variable'] == 'hello') {
   header('Location: http://site.com/index&variable=world');
   exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the variable or parameter in a url is preceded with a `?` and then they are separated by `&`.

To get what you want just use this link:

```
<a href="http://site.com/index?variable=world&anothervariable=dontchangeme">Click me</a>
```

but this is hardcoded and not dynamic in the sense that you can change the value of the parameter dynamically so my answer is probably not the best.

Comment: I clarified my answer, I'd like to link to a URL with GET variables without changing other variables already in the URL

Comment: But that would still get rid of other variables already in the URL, right?

Comment: yes, sorry, I've just read the updated question. My answer is not what you need, I apologise! I will update but it probably won't be as good as deceze's answer

Answer (score 0):

this should do it.

```
<a href="variable=world <?php foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {echo '&&'.$key.'='.$value}">Click me</a>
```