# Append data to GET parameter

Tags: php, parameters, get, send

I simply need to send data to a GET parameter on a different host but I fail to find a suitable function within PHP for that occasion. That's my only question.

For example send any value for the information parameter:

```
http://example.com/obtainer.php?information=
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Check this out you might like it...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809774/manipulate-a-url-string-by-adding-get-parameters

Comment: why not just url encode the string and send like http://example.com/obtainer.php?information=hello%20something

Comment: I need to send it from a different host
@spt025 I think you should re-read my question

Comment: Can you explain bit more..like what type of host..??

Answer (score 0):

Query strings (_GET) parameter are constructed like;

```
www.example.com/index.php?param1=value&param2=value
```

If you're sending any value to the information parameter via form, do the following;

```
<form action="" method="get">
 <input type="text" name="information" value="" />
 <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

However, if you're sending the data via link, write it manually, like so;

```
<a href="index.php?information=hello">Link</a>
```

Remember, when putting string into the query string, ensure you use [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

Comment: Can you please read my question again? First of all I said it's on a different host and second I don't need a simple link but a php function..

Comment: I read it multiple times before submitting, and failed to see "different host" - my apologies. Simply change the `action` in the form, or the `href` link to the host. The term `host` do you mean another website, or multiple servers for one site?

Comment: On multiple backend servers, or a single server? If it's the latter, my example is fine, right?

Comment: Ok for the third time "I don't need a simple link but a php function.. "

Comment: Have you looked into http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php ?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are sending something to `http://example.com/obtainer.php`, you can try the following PHP function...

```
file_get_contents('http://example.com/obtainer.php?information='.urlencode('whatever');
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you are trying to do. If you're trying to use an API for another website, than what you want is the file_get_contents function. For example:

```
<?php
$username = 'S1nus';
?>
<img src=<?php echo "'" . file_get_contents("http://psirup.com/api/getpsignature?user=$username") . "'";?>
```

would return [this image](http://psirup.com/api/getpsignature?user=s1nus) (Maybe not the best example, but the simplest API I can think of). (Don't forget to urlencode() the parameter, I almost forgot).

However, you may want to use [HttpRequest::send](http://php.net/manual/en/httprequest.send.php). This documentation explains how to use it with GETrequests.

Comment: "Don't forget to use urlencode, you failed to use it within your example

Comment: I think I should commit suicide.. Can any of you read or you are just here for the "lulz"? I DON'T NEED PECL FUNCTIONS OR FILE_GET_CONTENTS I NEED TO APPEND DATA TO AN EXTERNAL GET PARAMETER LOCATED ON A DIFFERENT WEBSITE

Comment: Woa, calm down there buddy. You're not making any sense. Append data to an external get parameter? What in the world does that mean? You understand how GET data works, right?

Comment: The question is do you understand what it means?