# Change URL using PHP without removing the existing variables

Tags: javascript, php

How can i change the URL using PHP, I asked this question before but i didn't receive any answer .
so this is my problem i want to add a pagination to my index page ,but in index page i have some icons that's filter some products , so the URL can be like that

> [www.mywebsite.com?id=66](http://www.mywebsite.com?id=66)

so the problem is when i click on next (pagination) the URL instead of this

> [www.mywebsite.com?id=66&page=2](http://www.mywebsite.com?id=66&page=2)

i get this

> [www.mywebsite.com?page=2](http://www.mywebsite.com?page=2)

so my question is how can i add that parm the URL without removing the existing one using PHP because i tried with JavaScript but i didn't success .

Comment: php outputs whatever you tell it to. it doesn't know what html is, nor does it care. if you want a url's query parameters to be preserved when PHP outputs an `<a>` link, then you have to put them in there yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use `http_build_query`

Example:

`http_build_query(array_merge($_GET, array('newVariable'=>'someValue')))`

Also - possible duplicate of [Manipulate a url string by adding GET parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809774/manipulate-a-url-string-by-adding-get-parameters)

Comment: how can i make this code work ** if ($page > 1) $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page={$prev}'>{$prevlabel}</a></li>"; **

Comment: I don't know what values those variables have, what the implementation is, or an explanation of how it is not working. I can't read your mind. It looks like you're generating a string from a couple different variables, under the condition `$page`, which I assume is an integer, is greater than 1. Where are you rendering it? So little information. Here's an article on PHP debugging I think you could benefit from: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-debug-in-php