# Is it possible to add GET statements to a URL when submitting a form to self?

Tags: php, get

Is it possible to have a link submit to self with GET variables in it?

`<a href='#?id=1234&c=2' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#mymodal'></a>`

Then when clicked the URL would look like this -

`example.com/test.php?msg=hello#?id=1234&c=2`

But it doesn't work / PHP doesn't see any of the variables after the #.

I have the following code on the same page (for testing) -

`echo $_GET['id'];`

And I want it to echo 1234

Is there another way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Parse the query string, add the variables you want, rebuild the query string.

Comment: Wait, hold on. Is it a link, or are you submitting a form? Those are two separate things.

Comment: I am not submitting a form, just a link. I got a little mixed up.

Comment: In that case, check this Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809774/manipulate-a-url-string-by-adding-get-parameters?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

If you want the query params you should put them *before* "#" and not after. When You put them after it, then your php script "won't see" them. Check out [this answer on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/498617/does-an-anchor-tag-come-before-the-query-string-or-after) for more.

Also your url example "example.com/test.php?msg=hello#?id=1234&c=2" has 2 "?" in it and it should not.