# replace an url parameter from form method get

Tags: php, forms, parameters, str-replace

A have a little problem with an url parameter.

I have a a form which uses method GET as I am only retrieving some data to get a resultlist. The data are not in any way secret to anyone.
In short I can in the form input some measurements on a roof and those numbers will be used to calculated how many rooftiles etc. I have to buy. In the form I can also input a percentage of extra rooftiles to be calculated, f.x. 3% extra. After ending the input and pressing calculated I will get an url that look like this:

```
index.php?page=matliste&width=8&length=12&angle-1=45&extra=3&zip=9000&tagfod=tagfod&finish_stone=dv&topsten=utop&angle=45&mainhouse=1&house=1&rooftype=uu&lang=dk&rooftiletype=1&rid=1&producent=h
```

In this I have 3% extra. But when I go back to the form and input f.x. 5% it will not be updated. It just inserts a new parameter so it will look something like this:

```
extra=5&extra=3
```

How can I remove the existing parameter and insert a new one with the new number?

I am using this to build the query from the form fields:

```
if($_GET["newpage"] == "matliste") {   
    $get_elements = array_filter($_GET, "strlen");        

    $url = http_build_query($get_elements);

    $search_pattern = array();
    $search_pattern[0] = "/([?&]newpage)=[^&]*/";
    $search_pattern[1] = "/([?&]next)=[^&]*/";
    $search_pattern[2] = "/angle_\d+/";

    $search_replacements = array();
    $search_replacements[0] = '';
    $search_replacements[1] = '';
    $search_replacements[2] = 'angle';

    $new_url = preg_replace($search_pattern, $search_replacements, $url);

    header("Location: index.php?page=". $_GET["newpage"] ."&".$new_url);
}
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100538/php-add-update-a-parameter-in-a-url/4101638#4101638

Comment: I am not sure how I can use the addUrlParameter with my example

Comment: replace your code, with that one. pass the URL to be modified, the URL variable name and its new value.

Comment: Can I do that dynamically? I don't know what parameter(s) to change as it is based on what the user which to change in the form. He might choose to enter only one new number in any given field.

Comment: You might think I am completely stupid, but can you give me an example? :) I have looked at this so much that I am totally blind of finding the solution.

Comment: First of all, get rid of preg_replace, and iterate using foreach. In the iterator body, just call addURLParameter to update an URL variable.

Comment: Garh... foreach didn't even cross my mind! Thank you very much. It still doesn't replace the parameter value, but I believe that is because of something else! 

Will you make an answer! Thanks!

Comment: I still think this is a duplicate of that answer. Upvote that person's answer if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing all that, just stick the values you have back into the form and let the browser recreate the query string for you.