# How to work with $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']

Tags: php

How to work with $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] and pagination?

When my table is sorted by this link:

```
<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?sort_name=name&sort=asc" title="'.$lang['sorteer_asc'].'"></a>
```

My url becomes: relation.php?sort_name=adres&sort=asc

The I use an pagination link:

```
echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'].'&page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a> ';
```

And the url becomes: relation.php?sort_name=adres&sort=asc&page=2

So far so good but when browsing to other pages it can be as long as:
relation.php?sort_name=adres&sort=asc&page=2&page=3&page=14&page=23&page=27

The age keeps appearing because of the $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], how can I clean up my url with only keeping the last page and ?sort_name=adres&sort=asc.

Or do you suggest an other solution of ordering and pagination?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change single variable value in querystring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037909/change-single-variable-value-in-querystring)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Instead of reusing `QUERY_STRING`, you should assemble it anew with [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php).

```
// Merge $_GET with new parameter
$QS = http_build_query(array_merge($_GET, array("page"=>2)));

// You should apply htmlspecialchars() on the path prior outputting:
echo "<a href='" . htmlspecialchars("$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?$QS") . "'> $i </a>";
```

Thus you have all current `$_GET` parameters included, but can add or replace entries with new values. And it's ensured that each appears only once.

Comment: With this solution I got the current and the last page in the url ?page=2&page=9

Comment: @Muiter: Then the array `+` is insufficient. Use `http_build_query(array_merge($_GET, array("page"=>$i)));` instead. With **array_merge** duplicate entries are reliably replaced. -- Oh and don't append the `."&page=9"` yourself like in your example. `$QS` already contains the page parameter then. You must of course only use the inner `array("page"=>$i)`.

Comment: @mario this also removes the part of the url '?sort_name=adres&sort=asc'

Comment: @mario: I have uploaded my pagination file: www.pws.nl/pagination.rar

Comment: @Muiter: Seems you are still using `$_SERVER[QUERY_STRING]`. Can't help with that.

Comment: Yes, it's your **original** code. And no, I cannot help with that. Since you are not using any part of the suggested solution, there's no option to debug the problems with the suggested solution.

Answer (score 0):

Create a link builder ( simple php whitch make array( "a" => "b", "c" => "d" ) into ?a=b&c=d 
and rebuild it each time ( eg. put there "sort_name" => ... , "sort" => ..., "page" => ... )

If you still want to use QUERY_STRING - check if it contains &page=... and replace it ( both made by regexp )

Answer (score 0):

Don't use QueryString, just create a variable at the beginning of your script:

```
$pagerUrl = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?sort_name='.$_GET['sort_name']&sort=$_GET['sort'];
```

And use it in your link:

```
echo '<a href="'.$pagerUrl.'&page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a> ';
```

Comment: PHP_SELF is always going to have the previous query variables appended to the end, that's the root of the OP's problem.

Comment: No, that's not true, the query variables are included only in the $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], not in $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], so QUERY_STRING is the problem

Comment: Wow, you know i just dumped a phpinfo() on my local server and somehow confused REQUEST_URI with PHP_SELF. Touché, I stand corrected--my apologies.

Comment: This code is vulnerable for XSS. Never echo a $_GET directly w/o filtering.