# what is $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] ? how it works?

Tags: php

```
$Q = explode("/", $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]);
```

What can be the possible `$Q`'s value?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856480/how-to-work-with-serverquery-string

Comment: Depends on what page is being visited, whether it has url rewriting.. etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Explode : Returns an array of strings, each of which is a substring of string formed by splitting it on boundaries formed by the string delimiter.

> array explode ( string $delimiter , string $string [, int $limit ] )

Run this Code to Understand :

```
/* A string that doesn't contain the delimiter will simply return a one-length array of the original string. */

$input1 = "hello";
$input2 = "hello,there";
var_dump( explode( ',', $input1 ) );
var_dump( explode( ',', $input2 ) );
```

**The above example will output:**

```
array(1)
(
    [0] => string(5) "hello"
)
array(2)
(
    [0] => string(5) "hello"
    [1] => string(5) "there"
)
```

And, In Your Case, Your Current Query String will be Splited into Array. And, Each / will be a array item.

Like if 
     explode( '/', 'foo/bar')

Array will contain Foo and Bar into seperate index.

For More :
Explode : [Explode Details from PHP.NET](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)
$_SERVER : [$_Server Details from PHP.NET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Comment: Ya, if you find this usefull then, mark as answer. And, You welcome.

Answer (score 15):

for example you have a URL in browser like this

```
relation.php?variable1/variable2/variable3
```

and you want the get the value after the `?`
then `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` helps you to determine the part the string after the `?`

and according to your question

```
$Q = explode("/", $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]);
```

variable `$Q` is an array with the values like

```
Array
(
  [0] => variable1
  [1] => variable2
  [2] => variable3
)
```

take a look on the [$_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) and [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Comment: There is the specific php function [parse_str()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php), which you can use instead of explode

Answer (score 4):

If a page is accessed via any query string, $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] fetches that query string.

Example :

```
<?php  
echo "The query string is: ".$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];  
?>
```

If the above php code is saved with a filename of QUERY_STRING.php and if you add '?tutorial=php&section=super-globals' `(i.e. QUERY_STRING.php?tutorial=php&section=super-globals);` it will print this string in the page since you have asked the script to print $SERVER['QUERY_STRING'].

For more info goto :

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php