# How to pass multiple variables to URL with GET

Tags: php

I have a php page that displays results from a mysqli query.

At the top I have the ever present #perpage and order by selectors so the user can select what they want.

```
<form action="" method="GET">
<select name="perpage" onchange="this.form.submit()">
<?php 
                              if (isset($_GET['perpage'])) {print"<option value='".$_GET['perpage']."'>".$_GET['perpage']."</option>";}
                              if (isset($_GET['perpage']) && $_GET['perpage']==10) {} else {print"<option value='10'>10</option>";}
                              if (isset($_GET['perpage']) && $_GET['perpage']==20) {} else {print"<option value='20'>20</option>";}
                              if (isset($_GET['perpage']) && $_GET['perpage']==30) {} else {print"<option value='30'>30</option>";}
                              ?>
</select>
</form>
```

and this one for the orderby

```
<form action="" method="">
<select name="order" onchange="this.form.submit()">
<option value="asc">Ascending</option>
<option value="desc">Descending</option>
</select>
</form>
```

If my current URL is results.php?perpage=30 and i try and set the order by it bcomes results.php?orderby=desc and vice versa. I would need ot to simply append the second variable to the end of the URL if one is already set.

have tried setting the action to the current URL using $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] and it does the same thing.

Comment: The accepted answer of [this question][1] may be useful to you (possible dupe).

It seems like $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] superglobal is what you are looking for.
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856480/how-to-work-with-serverquery-string

Comment: @ThomasAndrews i added the order by one to the question

Answer (score 0):

It does work for me ...

Put this in a index.php file:

```
<?php print_r($_GET); ?>

<form action="" method="GET">
    <select name="perpage" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <?php 
        if (isset($_GET['perpage'])) { print "<option value='".$_GET['perpage']."'>".$_GET['perpage']."</option>"; }
        if (isset($_GET['perpage']) && $_GET['perpage']==10) {} else { print "<option value='10'>10</option>"; }
        if (isset($_GET['perpage']) && $_GET['perpage']==20) {} else { print "<option value='20'>20</option>"; }
        if (isset($_GET['perpage']) && $_GET['perpage']==30) {} else { print "<option value='30'>30</option>"; }
        ?>
    </select>
</form>
```

Call the page like this in your browser: `http://localhost/index.php?perpage=20`

Comment: One of them by themselves work. sorry i hadnt included the other. the problem is when one var is set and you try and change the other one

Answer (score 0):

Put your orderby in other select by example:

```
<form action="process-form.php" method="GET">
    <select name="orderby">
        <option value="ASC">ASC</option>
        <option value="DESC">DESC</option>
    </select>
    <select name="perpage" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <?php 
            if (isset($_GET['perpage'])) {
                print"<option value='".$_GET['perpage']."'>".$_GET['perpage']."</option>";
            }

            if (isset($_GET['perpage']) && $_GET['perpage']==10) {} 

            else {
                print"<option value='10'>10</option>";
            }

            if (isset($_GET['perpage']) && $_GET['perpage']==20) {} else {
                print"<option value='20'>20</option>";
            }

            if (isset($_GET['perpage']) && $_GET['perpage']==30) {} else {
                print"<option value='30'>30</option>";
            }
        ?>
    </select>
</form>
```

And, when submit your form will send two parameters.

In PHP file "process-form.php" you can get the parameters like this:

```
$_GET["orderby"]
```

and

```
$_GET["perpage"]
```

Comment: I did this as per another posters suggestion however now it only allows to set both vars and not only one.

Comment: Is required submit the form on change value of the fields?