# Pass current URL on form submit

Tags: php, forms

As a continuation of [Adding Values to a Query String in a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9100764/add-values-to-a-query-string-in-a-url), I have a search box that will add additional arguments to the current URL.

```
http://example.com/?s=original+new+arguments&fq=category
```

The form code looks like this:

```
<form id="FilterSearch" method="get" action="http://example.com/search_result.php">
```

Where search_result.php is just a new page I created to parse the submit and redirect using the new URL.

How can I pass the original URL to search_result.php so that I can then manipulate the URL?

**EDIT #1** : I added a hidden input:

```
<?php $current_url = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; ?>
<input type="hidden" name="current_url" value="<?php $current_url; ?>" />
<input name="send" id="send" type="submit" value="Search" />
```

My output is only adding the arguments to the submission page (search_result.php) and not the intended query page.

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['send'])){
                $searchField = urlencode($_GET['SearchField']);
                $location =  $_GET['current_url'];
                $location = preg_replace($location, '/([?&]s=)([^&]+)/', '$1$2+'.$searchField);
                header('Location: '.$location);
                }
?>
```

I'm either passing them wrong or getting them wrong or both!

**EDIT #2** : Output URL is like:

```
http://example.com/wp-content/themes/child_theme/search_result.php?SearchField=newTerm&current_url=www.example.com%2F%3Fs%3DoldTerm%26searchsubmit%3D&send=Search
```

**EDIT #3**
I echoed the output URL and it's correct. I got rid of the preg_match just to see if I could get the same URL when I processed the form. Interestingly, I got a page not found. I decided to add **http://** the header and it worked:

```
header('Location: http://'.$location);
```

So therefore, I believe that the only thing wrong here is the preg_replace.

Comment: It looks like you need to do value="<?php echo $current_url; ?>". You could also use $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] like dfsq suggests as an alternative to this method, but it's not always reliable.

Comment: Are you getting any value in your $location variable?

Comment: see the second edit (output url)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you're looking for the hidden input.

Something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="current_url" value="(Current URL here)" />
```

Then access it just like you would any other $_GET or $_POST parameter.

---

EDIT to respond to edits:

Could you `echo $location; die;` after this line:

```
$location =  $_GET['current_url'];
```

and let me know what the output is? This will tell us whether it's being passed incorrectly or processed incorrectly.

Comment: Edited my answer to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` in your `search_result.php`. Another option is to use hidden input, but I would go with the first one.

Comment: I disagree, referer may not be as stable on some environments. If it's small effort to use a hidden input, use that method instead.

Answer (score 0):

The better way to get current URl you create a hidden input and in that you pass current URL and catch in server end. i.e.

```
<input type="hidden" name="cur_url" value="(your Current URL here)" />
```