# URL argument value replacing

Tags: php, string, url

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change single variable value in querystring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037909/change-single-variable-value-in-querystring)

For example: `www.example.com/feeds?arg1=xyz&arg2=abc$arg3=pqr`. I want to replace the arg2 value with say 123 to get `www.example.com/feeds?arg1=xyz&arg2=123$arg3=pqr`. Please suggest an easiest way to attain that.

Comment: Take a look at `parse_url` and `parse_str`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Process is simple.

1. Parse the query part.
2. use [parse_str](http://php.net/parse_str) to extract each variable in the query
3. Replace it.
4. use [http_build_query](http://php.net/http_build_query) to build the query again
5. put this query string to main url

See this code.

```
$str = "www.example.com/feeds?arg1=xyz&arg2=abc$arg3=pqr";
$p = strpos($str, "?");
if($p!==false){
    $q = substr($str, $p+1);
    parse_str($q, $u);
    $u['arg2']='new value';
    $q=http_build_query($u);
    $str = substr($str, 0, $p). "?". $q;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$url = "?";
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
  if ($key != 'arg2') {
    $url .= "$key=$value&";
  }
}
$url .= "arg2=123"; // has arg=123 at the very end
```

Once you have this, all you have to do is:

```
header("Location: $url");
```

Since you didn't provide anything before the `?`, it will simply change the `$_GET` parameters, which is what you need anyway.